# symbolic model function passing to lmfit

Tags: python, sympy, lmfit

symbolic model function passing
Hi!
I stuck in my fitting due to my symbolic function,
Please kindly let me know how this issue could be solved here is my code, I need to pass tow independent_var which are xCl and XI and a is parameter:

```
import numpy as np
import lmfit
import sympy as sp    
anion = {'I': 1, 'Cl': 1}
xa = {'xI': 0.2, 'xCl': 0.3}
xCl = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
xI = [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, 0.8, 0.11, 0.12]

def g(xa, anion, a):
    xzc = 0
    for k1, k2 in zip(anion, xa):
        xzc += sp.symbols(f"x{k1}") * sp.symbols(f"x{k2}") + a
    return xzc
obj = lmfit.Model(g, independent_vars=['xCl', 'xI'])
pars = obj.make_params(a=0.1)

result = mod.fit(ydat, pars, xCl, xI)
print(result.fit_report())
```

but I' ve found;

```
**************************************************
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Zohreh\MainZohreh\postdoc-field\CSU\pythonProject\simple_Lmfit.py", line 36, in <module>
    obj = lmfit.Model(g, independent_vars=['xCl', 'xI'])
  File "C:\Users\Zohreh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\lmfit\model.py", line 277, in __init__
    self._parse_params()
  File "C:\Users\Zohreh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\lmfit\model.py", line 541, in _parse_params
    raise ValueError(self._invalid_ivar % (arg, fname))
ValueError: Invalid independent variable name ('xCl') for function g
*********************************************************
```

Comment: I don't use `lmfit`, but it looks like it builds on/uses `scipy/numpy`.  You cannot, in general, plug `sympy` expressions into `numpy` code.  A few calculations work, but must fail at some point or other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, it is necessary to use lambdify to change sympy equation to numpy one. this way it it will be granted that ndarray float are sent to lmfit model.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The `independent_vars` passed to `lmfit.Model` must match the names of the function arguments of the model function.  In your case, the model function has a signature of `g(xa, anion, a)` so those would be `xa`, `anion`, and `a`.  Neither `xCl` nor `xI` makes sense as independent variables - they aren't variables to the model function at all.    That is what the exception

`ValueError: Invalid independent variable name ('xCl') for function g`

is expressing.

Comment: All my problem is that I cant explicitly name independent variables and parameters. After lots of coding I just have a sympy expression. Is there any way to automatically make a func using independent variables and parameters and sympy expression that is just includes independent variables and parameters .

Comment: Infact my issue related to lmfit is gone. But I 'm not familiar how to make function automatically.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "make function automatically".  In order to use `lmfit.Model`, one does have to express the model they want to compare to data as a Python function.  The arguments of that "model function" will be treated either as "variable Parameters" or as "independent variables" in the fitting process.  I do not really understand what you are trying to do, or why you think using `sympy` will help with building a model for `lmfit`.  A minimal working example showing what you are doing might help, but starting from one of the many lmfit examples might be even better.